# C++ Rvalue and move

Tags: c++, c++11

Please help to understand on below

```
class Demo {};
    Demo && fun() {
        Demo d;
        cout << "Addres of d in fun " << &d << endl;
        return move(d);
    }
int main()
{
    Demo && d = fun() 
}
```

Is this the correct way to return object ??

Comment: Correct syntax wouldn't hurt!

Answer (score 5):

It is undefined behaviour to return a reference to a local variable, so no, this code is not OK.

A correct way to return an object is to return a prvalue:

```
Demo fu(n) {
  Demo d;
  return d;   // "move(d)" is implied
}

Demo && d = fun();  // OK, reference binds to temporary and extends its lifetime
```

Comment: I think that is doesn't work if Demo hasn't a copy constructor, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @JeanPierreDudey: It works as long as `Demo` has a move constructor. Otherwise, say `return {};` to direct-initialize the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, returning the object by value gives you the simplest code and optimal performance:

```
Demo fun() {
    Demo d;
    return d;
}
int main() {
    Demo d = fun();
}
```

If Demo were an expensive-to-copy, cheap-to-move type such as `std::vector`, move semantics would kick in automatically to avoid the copy---no `&&` required.